# Does God want us to be subservient to him?

Tags: other-religions

One of the things that disturbs me about abrahamic religions is that they consider secular movies, music and even job to be sinful.  In Islam, music and poetry is considered is haram as they say it takes you away from the rememberance of god. In Christianity, they say that satan makes secular music (ezeikel 28:13) .A song must explicitly have the word Jesus in it to be christian .Whereas Krishna said in Bhagwad Geeta that one has to be poetic or an expert in whatever art he's blessed with. He has to be diligent as well . Aren't good deeds enough for a person to get moksha? A Father would be much happier to see his son progressing and being a good person instead of having a son who keeps telling him yeah I honor you. I respect you. I love you.   You're my lord . I mean how can someone forget God. This agenda of abrahamic religions seems absurd to me. (not trying to be condescending)

Comment: According to tatvavada you are not subservient but totally dependent for every action that we say for every action we do "Hari Kartha Na Aham Kartha" means Hari does we didn't do

Comment: Hi, There are significant disconnects between the several parts of the question. Coherence is lacking between 1) title of the question 2) the first part of the description (on music and such) 3) question on whether good deeds are enough for moksha 4) Issues with reiterated subservience. You might want to edit the question to give clarity and focus for those who want to answer.

Comment: There is no one 'attitude' towards God. Whether you see the Lord as yourself as a friend, lover, or servant (subservient) of the Lord depends upon the individual's makeup. Your guru will know your attitude.

Comment: @swamivishwananda my namastae first but I disagree seeing yourself as god and seeing god as friend, etc are not same there is sea of difference

Comment: @prasannaragothaman - I think Swami was saying that they are different. as you say, therefore our choice will be individual as suits us. I feel the OP is right to question the idea of subservience but might be better off asking on a forum where someone believes in this idea of God. The Abrahamic religions are not absurd but the form they take in some of their sects and cults may well be. If you read someone like David Bentley Hart or Keith Ward you may find a less garbled explanation. .

Comment: @PeterJ I agree with you and swami on seeing god as friend etc  this was stated by prahlad in navavidha bakthi (9 ways to worship god) but not myself as god but I don't much about Abrahmic religion so nothing to comment..

Comment: Why be so disturbed? They aren't wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple questions here. Is good deeds a step towards Moksha ? Undoubtedly. There are many references which talk about the superexcellence of selfless sacrifice.

Here we find in [Gita](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/6/40),

> The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: Son of Pṛthā, a transcendentalist engaged in auspicious activities does not meet with destruction either in this world or in the spiritual world; one who does good, My friend, is never overcome by evil.

Again in [Gita](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/12/13-14),

> One who is not envious but is a kind friend to all living entities, who does not think himself a proprietor and is free from false ego, who is equal in both happiness and distress, who is tolerant, always satisﬁed, self-controlled, and engaged in devotional service with determination, his mind and intelligence ﬁxed on Me – such a devotee of Mine is very dear to Me.

We find in [Srimad Bhagavatam](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/7/44),

> It is said that great personalities almost always accept voluntary suffering because of the suffering of people in general. This is considered the highest method of worshiping the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who is present in everyone’s heart.

and in [Srimad Bhagavatam](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/10/9),

> If one is unhappy to see the distress of other living beings and happy to see their happiness, his religious principles are appreciated as imperishable by exalted persons who are considered pious and benevolent.

Now 2nd question is is serving God necessary for Moksha? Krishna says in the [Gita](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/29),

> I envy no one, nor am I partial to anyone. I am equal to all. But whoever renders service unto Me in devotion is a friend, is in Me, and I am also a friend to him.

and in [Gita](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/14/26),

> One who engages in full devotional service, unfailing in all circumstances, at once transcends the modes of material nature and thus comes to the level of Brahman.

and [Bhagavatam](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/2/6) says,

> The supreme occupation [dharma] for all humanity is that by which men can attain to loving devotional service unto the transcendent Lord. Such devotional service must be unmotivated and uninterrupted to completely satisfy the self.

What this means is that service to God, spontaneous loving service is a means and ends for Moksha because it is the nature of the jiva to serve Krishna and in that it attains an eternal liberated state, so the service is eternal, joyful and not tiring.

Comment: what about 3rd question? how do poetry, music, movies, job etc, as abrahamic faiths claim, take us away from the rememberance of God? doesn't it seem absurd? We know that Krishna exists and nothing can make us forget that fact.

Comment: Hinduism does have a strict set of regulative principles. We do need to follow it. The primary difference is Abrahamic religions are based on the idea of fear of God, while Bhakti is based on the idea of love of God. When there is genuine love for God, naturally you will use all your skills like music poetry art in service of God. You can read how Ambarisha Maharaja devoted all His senses in the service of Krishna in the Bhagavatam.  Srila Prabhupada has asked us to follow 4 regulative principles :a. No meat eating b. No illicit sex c. No intoxication d. No gambling.

Comment: To your direct question, we can get on with our usual activities like job, good clean music, clean entertainment while simultaneously remembering Krishna and following regulative principles.

Comment: " Srila Prabhupada has asked us to follow 4 regulative principles :a. No meat eating b. No illicit sex c. No intoxication d. No gambling." Srila Prabhupada is NOT god. I know he is referring to the sins of the Kali yuga. Moreover, the discussion about whether Krishna is god himself is also another discussion within hinduism.

Comment: doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Good deeds to do not lead to moksha. Good deeds lead to the various heavens and rebirth. The *Mundaka Upanishad* III.ii.3 says (Swami Vivekananda translator):

> This Atman is not to be attained by the study of the Vedas, nor by the highest intellect, nor by much learning. Whom the Atman seeks, he gets, the Atman; unto him He discloses His glory.

Doing good works is merely good conduct in this world. *Brahma Sutras* 3.1.11 (available here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras) says:

> But (conduct) is merely good and evil work; thus (the sage) Badari (thinks).

What matters is purity of heart. You need to make your heart pure, to want only the Lord.

The 'attitude' a devotee takes to the Lord (friend, servant, lover, etc.) depends upon one's own individual makeup. There is no one attitude in Hinduism.